# SE chrome notification

Tags: discussion, support, notifications, login

Can you guys suggest a good StackExchange chrome extension which will focus on things like votes or notifications?

For example the notifications which is shown in the site itself is very good and i want it in my chrome extension toolbar as:

[image: SE]

> The extension which was available no longer works...when i tried to log-in i got [this page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6206245?p=openid&rd=1#survey=true):

[image: openid 2.0]

So...Is this a problem with SE??

Is such an extension available...I didn't find it...Thanks a lot!
By the way i am not aware of a suitable tag for this question...this may be silly but a lot of my friends have also been asking for this feature...so please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We upgraded all our systems from Google OpenID to Google OAuth, so I'm betting on this being the problem with the extension you had before, not us.

Does the extension you've been using require you to authenticate with Google? At what point do you get redirected to that support page?

Comment: It raises an error when "I login through google"...BTW i had come to know of this app from : (http://stackapps.com/questions/1592/stack-exchange-notifier-chrome-extension)

Comment: BTW is such an official extension available?

Comment: @NeilRoy Yeah, that extension will need to be updated. Considering that the last changelog note happens to be from 2010, I unfortunately don't have high hopes that it will be. There's no official extension available at this time... but I'll see if I can throw something together in my spare time unless someone beats me to it (either with a new one or with a link to an existing extension).